# Replacing multiple space in every line by comma

Tags: python, csv

How can I replace multiple whitespaces for every lines by comma, I'm using tabulate and been trying to figure out how

**Here's a my code:**

```
def print_extensions(self):       
    i = InternetExplorer(self.os)
    content1 = tabulate(i.extensions(), headers="keys", tablefmt="plain")               
    text_file=open("output.csv","w")
    text_file.write(content1)
    text_file.close()
```

**My CSV output:**

where • = whitespace

```
path•••••name•••••id
C:\Windows•••••Microsoft•••••{CFBFAE00}
```

**Expected CSV output:**

```
path,name,id
C:\Windows,Microsoft,{CFBFAE00}
```

Comment: `re.sub('\s+', ',', line)` should do that.

Comment: that replaced my multiple whitespace but the result became 1 line only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

data = ["some", "header"], ["and", "data"]

with open("test.csv", "w") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you'd be better off using Python's standard
[`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

For example:

```
import csv

data = ["some", "header"], ["and", "data"]

with open("test.csv", "w") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

produces the file

```
some,header
and,data
```

Tabulate is really more intended for pretty-printing. I certainly wouldn't suggest producing CSV files by parsing the output of tabulate with regular expressions.